# Different width on webkit scrollbars

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, scrollbar, overflow

**Problem**

I have two divs with overflow scrollbars. Both have the same width. Still, they get different width.

It's a CSS problem but I added some JS. It makes it possible to drag the bottom scrollbar to affect the top scrollbar.

I only expect it to work with webkit browsers like Chrome.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jedrga5w/3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="mmt">
    <div class="mmt-scrollbar">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="mmt-cropped">
        <div>Content2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mmt-cropped {
    height: 200px;
    background: #eee;
}
.mmt-cropped,
.mmt-scrollbar {
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: 532px;
}

.mmt-cropped div,
.mmt-scrollbar div {
   width: 770px;
}

.mmt-cropped::-webkit-scrollbar,
.mmt-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.mmt-cropped::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal,
.mmt-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 11px;
}

.mmt-cropped::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb,
.mmt-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.mmt-cropped::-webkit-scrollbar-track,
.mmt-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track { 
    background-color: #fff; 
    border-radius: 8px; 
}

.mmt-scrollbar,
.mmt-scrollbar div {
    height: 11px;
}
```

**JS - Not required**

Just to connect the bottom scroll to the top scoll. Not required but it makes it easier to spot the problem.

```
jQuery(window).load(function($) {
    $('.mmt-cropped').scroll(function(){
         $('.mmt-scrollbar').scrollLeft( $('.mmt-cropped').scrollLeft() );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/jedrga5w/4/)**

css

```
.mmt-scrollbar,
.mmt-scrollbar div {
    height: 11px;
    overflow-y:hidden; /* add this as there is a vertical scrollbar bar which is occupying some space */ 
}
```

you can find the scrollbar by giving some height to (**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/jedrga5w/5/)**)

```
.mmt-scrollbar,
.mmt-scrollbar div {
    height: 100px;
}
```

---

**Notice: the vertical scrollbar to the right of `.mmt-scrollbar div` after giving it some height.**

[image]